# How can we add system attribute in magento

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.9, custom-attributes

Hi guys I am working in magento 1.9 i want to add new custom system attribute like we have by default name, sku etc.

```
$_attribute_data = array(
                        'attribute_code' => $wholedata['attribute_code'],
                        'is_global' => '1',
                        'frontend_input' => 'text',
                        'default_value_text' => '',
                        'default_value_yesno' => '0',
                        'default_value_date' => '',
                        'default_value_textarea' => '',
                        'is_unique' => '0',
                        'is_required' => '0',
                        //'apply_to' => '0',
                        'is_configurable' => '0',
                        'is_searchable' => '0',
                        'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => '1',
                        'is_comparable' => '0',
                        'is_used_for_price_rules' => '0',
                        'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => '0',
                        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => '1',
                        'is_visible_on_front' => '0',
                        'used_in_product_listing' => '0',
                        'used_for_sort_by' => '0',
                        'frontend_label' => $wholedata['attribute_label'],
                        'user_defined' => false
                    );
```

I have created attribute using these settings but its still not system attribute i have searched a lot and find this solution to make

> 'user_defined' => false

for system attribute it must be false but still its not making as a system attribute in admin panel attributes list its showing **system no** on this newly created attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can change is_user_defined to 0 in table eav_attribute it will make that attribute to system

Answer (score 0):

You can try add this param `'is_system' => 1` to your attribute data, that would solve your issue.

Hope that help

Comment: Still its not making it a system... in admin its showing system no